# How make prod and dev envs using git

Tags: git, workflow

I’d like to improve my workflow so I decided myself use git.

Till now for my projects, on my web server, I had 2 folders which are prod and dev.

Once modifications are over I sync both of my folders.

I tried to use git like this way :

```
// on my prod folder
$ git init 
$ git add *
$ git commit -a
```

Then on parent folder

```
$ git clone prod dev
```

Works like a charm I got my dev folder as perfect cot of prod
But now once my modifications are ok I can’t commit to prod. How can I achieve that ?! Thx

**EDIT**

Here is my organization tree on my web server :

```
home
|--git
   |--.ssh
   |--repositories
      |-- myfirstrepo.git
          |-- index.html
```

What I'm trying to achieve is from `/var/www`

```
$ git clone /home/git/repositories/myfirstrepo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/myfirstrepo_wc/.git/
```

I got the clone of my repo in

```
var
|--www
   |--myfirstrepo_wc
      |--index.html
```

So now I make change to my index.html file in `/var/www/myfirstrepo_wc` then

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   www/index.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Make commit

```
$ git commit -a
[master d19749d] first commit from working copy
Committer: root <root@localhost.localdomain>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

If the identity used for this commit is wrong, you can fix it with:

git commit --amend --author='Your Name <you@example.com>'

1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

then want to pull to my repo who is in `/home/git/repositories/myfirstrepo.git`

```
$ git pull origin master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 358 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /git/myfirstrepo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/git/myfirstrepo.git'
```

Comment: It seems you are not getting how git works, Try reading these before you do anything else.
[Version Control](https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/),

[Distributed Version Control](https://betterexplained.com/articles/intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated/),

[Git](https://betterexplained.com/articles/aha-moments-when-learning-git/)

Comment: Very useful thx... the question is not what I understand or not, the point is that my company wants this organization. The first reason is that our clients want see the development version to validate the development. And we also don’t want pull repo on each developer’s desktop. Maybe you have better solution who fill the needs ?

Comment: Why have separate repos for prod/dev? You could easily have two folders or even two branches...

Comment: Interesting evolutionxbox I already have 2 folders. Inside each I have one .git folder. Could you provide me more details ?! And what about our clients? They will still able to view the dev version ?

Comment: I think you are conflating code versioning with building/deploying. You keep all the versions, including current "prod", "dev" and issue branches, etc, in a single git repo. However, using branches or [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), you can deploy different versions of your code to different staging areas. So you could build/deploy your "prod" branch to a production server/folder, your "test"/"QA" branch to a "QA" server and your "dev" branch to a "dev" server.

Comment: You can also use tools like Jenkins to automatically listen for changes to particular branches then start a deployment to a particular server. So if you move a commit from dev to QA, Jenkins will automatically build the QA branch and then deploy to your QA server. Same with moving a commit from QA to Prod.

Comment: JBD I keep this tips in mind for later. I’d like to make git works with my needs first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution :

```
$git remote add origin git@localhost:path/to/myfirstrepo.git
$git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Two folders with two .git folders means you have two git repositories, what you want is one folder with one .git folder and two branches, "prod" for production and "dev" for development, and to change between both you "checkout " the branch you want to see. Once you have this you can pull changes from dev to prod once you have finished making changes in dev and they are ready for prod, whilst this is not ideal it's a start. 
In your case you could:

1. We have 2 folders, each one with .git, let's delete the .git folder from dev
2. Open your git console on the prod folder, you will notice you are in branch master.
3. Type `git branch dev` , this will create a new branch called dev based on master (let's say that master = prod)
4. Type `git checkout dev` to move to the dev branch
5. Now copy the contents of the dev folder into the prod folder.
6. Type `git status` in the console and you will notice the files that were changed are marked as such.
7. Type git add -a to add all the changes to your development branch
8. Type git commit -m ""
9. now you have two branches in one repository.

Now let's assume you are happy with the changes in dev and want to add them to master,

1. Change your branch to master with `git checkout master`
2. Type `git pull dev`
3. and assuming no conflicts arise now master is in sync with develop.

Please bear in mind that this is just to get you started with git, try experimenting with toy repositories and using supplementary tools.

Comment: Interesting but the point 5 is weird.. if I copy my dev folder’s content into prod folder, my website is changing immediately without make commit or anything else.. so what is the advantage to use git if a simple copy do the job ?

Comment: @akio Well, git is for code versioning, deployment can be taken care of with other tools in conjuction with git, comments on your original post provide some examples.

Comment: I've edited my original post to provide more details